# Raise error from Sequel::Model if table does not exist?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I am starting to use Sequel for database connection handling in my Ruby application and hit a weird little snag. I created a model for my ETags table like so:

```
class ETag < Sequel::Model
end
```

Which should have gone out and found the `etags` table in my database, but it didn't. I think it was looking for `e_tags` instead, and created an empty model without any columns. The solution was to change it to this:

```
class Etag < Sequel::Model
end
```

Simple enough. However, I feel like my initial attempt should have raised an error. Is there a simple way to tell Sequel to raise an error when building a model if it can't find the underlying table in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently is not a way to do this automatically.  Trying to do it automatically would break many existing setups that do something like:

```
class ETag < Sequel::Model
  set_dataset :etags
end
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I was kind of hoping for an opt-in "strict mode" that you could enable. I'll dig into the code a bit but it's not looking too good!